# Trying to recreate 3des-ECB in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs, 3des

```
function crypt3() {
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

    var text = "Test";

    var options = {
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, 
        //  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("")
        
    };

    var key = "FRSF1P3b6fHiW/DXrK8ZJks5KAiyNpP0";
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
    var textWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text);
    //var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(textWordArray, keyHex, options);

    var base64String = encrypted.toString();

    console.log(base64ToHex("AHDJ/V+jo1s=")) //0070C9FD5FA3A35B
    console.log(base64ToHex(encrypted))

    console.log('encrypted val: ' + base64String);//yxLYGJ9O+sY=   CB12D8189F4EFAC6
}

function base64ToHex(str) {
    const raw = atob(str);
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
      const hex = raw.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
      result += (hex.length === 2 ? hex : '0' + hex);
    }
    return result.toUpperCase();
  }
```

Trying to recreate the functionality from https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/triple-des-encrypt-decrypt in nodejs but was unable to get similar results. What am I missing...any help would be appreciated.

Expected: AHDJ/V+jo1s=
Actual: yxLYGJ9O+sY=

Comment: The key you are using is NOT a hex string, it is probably a base64 encoded string, so the the parsing has to fail [note: I did not check the code].

Comment: CryptoJS and the website silently truncate the key to 24 bytes. Thus the key must be parsed with the `Utf8` encoder (analogous to the plaintext) and not with the `Hex` encoder. Then the expected ciphertext is produced.

Comment: The method `base64ToHex()` is actually not necessary, because CryptoJS provides both `Hex` and `Base64` encoders. Note that ECB is insecure and TripleDES slow.

Comment: That change did the trick!